# Understanding how splClassLoader Works

Tags: php, autoload

I’m developping a simple web application in OOP and I have trouble understanding how splClassLoader works to manage my autoloads. It blocks me for it cannot load properly the class because the include_path is the wrong one but I cannot find exactly how the problem occurs.

My App tries to load my AccountController throught the bootstrap file. The bootstrap files, through multiple autoload, uses the splClassLoader to find and load the right file.
I have followed the different steps and I found that my code becomes incorrect when reaching the « public function loadClass($className) » l.139 of the splClassLoader. The file looks for the class in «OCFram\AccountController » and not in «App\Frontend\Modules\Account\AccountController » as shown when dumping $className.

Before that point, my dumps show correct namespaces and includePath.

I cannot find how the $className is generated within the splClassLoader, I’m pretty sure understanding that step is key to understand my mistake. Can anyone guide me through understanding how $className is defined ? I feel it would help me find the mistake on my own for better understanding ;)

Below are the splClassLoader file, the bootstrap. Edit : I've added the trigger which happen in my Application.php file (parent of Frontend.php and Backend.php in my architecture) => L.45, this bit of code defines the default action when users arrive on the application.

splClassLoader .php :

```
<?php
/*
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INC`enter code here`LUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many individuals
 * and is licensed under the MIT license. For more information, see
 * <http://www.doctrine-project.org>.
 */
 
/**
 * SplClassLoader implementation that implements the technical interoperability
 * standards for PHP 5.3 namespaces and class names.
 *
 * http://groups.google.com/group/php-standards/web/psr-0-final-proposal?pli=1
 *
 *   // Example which loads classes for the Doctrine Common package in the
 *   // Doctrine\Common namespace.
 *   $classLoader = new SplClassLoader('Doctrine\Common', '/path/to/doctrine');
 *   $classLoader->register();
 *
 * @license http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html  MIT License
 * @author Jonathan H. Wage <jonwage@gmail.com>
 * @author Roman S. Borschel <roman@code-factory.org>
 * @author Matthew Weier O'Phinney <matthew@zend.com>
 * @author Kris Wallsmith <kris.wallsmith@gmail.com>
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien.potencier@symfony-project.org>
 */
class SplClassLoader
{
  private $_fileExtension = '.php';
  private $_namespace;
  private $_includePath;
  private $_namespaceSeparator = '\\';
 
  /**
   * Creates a new <tt>SplClassLoader</tt> that loads classes of the
   * specified namespace.
   * 
   * @param string $ns The namespace to use.
   */
  public function __construct($ns = null, $includePath = null)
  {
    $this->_namespace = $ns;
    $this->_includePath = $includePath;
  }
 
  /**
   * Sets the namespace separator used by classes in the namespace of this class loader.
   * 
   * @param string $sep The separator to use.
   */
  public function setNamespaceSeparator($sep)
  {
    $this->_namespaceSeparator = $sep;
  }
 
  /**
   * Gets the namespace seperator used by classes in the namespace of this class loader.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function getNamespaceSeparator()
  {
    return $this->_namespaceSeparator;
  }
 
  /**
   * Sets the base include path for all class files in the namespace of this class loader.
   * 
   * @param string $includePath
   */
  public function setIncludePath($includePath)
  {
    $this->_includePath = $includePath;
  }
 
  /**
   * Gets the base include path for all class files in the namespace of this class loader.
   *
   * @return string $includePath
   */
  public function getIncludePath()
  {
    return $this->_includePath;
  }
 
  /**
   * Sets the file extension of class files in the namespace of this class loader.
   * 
   * @param string $fileExtension
   */
  public function setFileExtension($fileExtension)
  {
    $this->_fileExtension = $fileExtension;
  }
 
  /**
   * Gets the file extension of class files in the namespace of this class loader.
   *
   * @return string $fileExtension
   */
  public function getFileExtension()
  {
    return $this->_fileExtension;
  }
 
  /**
   * Installs this class loader on the SPL autoload stack.
   */
  public function register()
  {
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
  }
 
  /**
   * Uninstalls this class loader from the SPL autoloader stack.
   */
  public function unregister()
  {
    spl_autoload_unregister(array($this, 'loadClass'));
  }
 
  /**
   * Loads the given class or interface.
   *
   * @param string $className The name of the class to load.
   * @return void
   */
  public function loadClass($className)
  {
    if (null === $this->_namespace || $this->_namespace.$this->_namespaceSeparator === substr($className, 0, strlen($this->_namespace.$this->_namespaceSeparator))) {
      $fileName = '';
      $namespace = '';
      if (false !== ($lastNsPos = strripos($className, $this->_namespaceSeparator))) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName = str_replace($this->_namespaceSeparator, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    var_dump('nameS :', $namespace, 'classe :', $className, 'file :', $fileName);
      }
      $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . $this->_fileExtension;

      require ($this->_includePath !== null ? $this->_includePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR : '') . $fileName;
    }
  }
}
```

Bootstrap.php :

```
<?php
const DEFAULT_APP = 'Frontend';

if (!isset($_GET['app']) || !file_exists(__DIR__.'\\..\\App\\'.$_GET['app'])) $_GET['app'] = DEFAULT_APP;

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/OCFram/SplClassLoader.php';

$OCFramLoader = new SplClassLoader('OCFram', dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib');
$OCFramLoader->register();
 
$appLoader = new SplClassLoader('App', dirname(__FILE__).'/..');
$appLoader->register();
 
$modelLoader = new SplClassLoader('Model', dirname(__FILE__).'/../App/Backend');
$modelLoader->register();
 
$entityLoader = new SplClassLoader('Entity', dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendors');
$entityLoader->register();

$accountLoader = new SplClassLoader('App', dirname(__FILE__).'/..');
$accountLoader->register();

$appClass = 'App\\'.$_GET['app'].'\\'.$_GET['app'].'Application';
$app = new $appClass;

$app->run();
```

Application.php :

```
<?php
namespace OCFram;
 
abstract class Application
{
  protected $httpRequest;
  protected $httpResponse;
  protected $name;
  protected $user;

 
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->httpRequest = new HTTPRequest($this);
    $this->httpResponse = new HTTPResponse($this);  
    $this->name = '';
    $this->user = new User($this);
  }

  //Méthode pour instancier le controlleur gérant l'action de la requête
  public function getController()
  {
    $router = new Router;
    $file = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../App/'.$this->name.'/config/routes.json';

    $data = file_get_contents($file);

    $routes = json_decode($data, true);

    foreach ($routes as $route)
      {
        $vars = [];
        
        if (isset($route->param) && $route->param != null)
        {
          $vars = explode(',', $route->param); 
        }

        $router->addRoute(new Route($route->module, $route->action, $route->param));

      }


    if($this->httpRequest->getData('action') == null){
      return new AccountController($this, 'Account', 'index');
    }else{
     try
      {
        $matchedRoute = $router->getRoute($this->httpRequest->getData('action'));
      }
      catch (\RuntimeException $e)
      {
        if ($e->getCode() == Router::NO_ROUTE)
        {
          // Si aucune route ne correspond, c'est que la page demandée n'existe pas.
          $this->httpResponse->redirect404();
        }
      }

      // On ajoute la variable éventuelle à l'objet.
      if ($this->httpRequest->getExists('var'))
      {
        $matchedRoute->setVar(getData('var'));
      }

      // On instancie le contrôleur.
      $controllerClass = 'App/'.$this->name.'/Modules/'.$matchedRoute->module().'/'.$matchedRoute->module().'Controller'; 
      return new $controllerClass($this, $matchedRoute->module(), $matchedRoute->action());     
    }
       
  }
 
  abstract public function run();
 
  public function httpRequest()
  {
    return $this->httpRequest;
  }
 
  public function httpResponse()
  {
    return $this->httpResponse;
  }
 
  public function name()
  {
    return $this->name;
  }
 
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->user;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share more detail, like the code that triggers the autoloader call

Comment: Also, even if I don't know that classloader and cannot vote against it: why not use any common autoloader, like the techniques provided by Composer?

Comment: If that class `Application` is part of the namespace `OCFram`, and you don't use and `use` statement to load `AccountController` from any other namespace, how should the classloader load if from any other?

Comment: Hey Nico ! This loader was furnish to me in the context of a lesson and I just went with it (not the best reason, but now I'm frustrated and intrigued by not finding the solution. Not understanding this code has to hide interesting loopholes I must work on). Thanks for this reply, I've added the trigger with the file Application.php.

Comment: " how should the classloader load if from any other?" => In theory, with any request going through the bootstrap with an App (front or back), a module and an action, the autoloader list every class available  and find a match. All I'm supposed to do in my code is to instanciate a class that exists in my application and who has a corresponding loader in the bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the classloader does. But without telling it where to look for that class, it just uses the **same** namespace of the class requesting the other one. You need a `use` statement like `use App\Frontend\Modules\Account\AccountController;` in your `Application.php`. No autoloader will load classes from random namespaces

Comment: Ok thanks ! It was a misunderstanding on my side ! Indeed I added "use App\Frontend\Modules\Account\AccountController;". It still showed an error but I realized I had redefined the constructor of my accountController in its own content rather than letting its parent's constructor do the job which shifted the namespace to use. I might have drowned my brain in this problem and created this second mistake looking for the first solution... Now it works :). Thank you for your guidance, I'll keep peeling my code. All the best !